# How to sort by newest product in magento2?

Tags: sorting, magento2

How can I sort by newest product in magento2?

[image: Sort options]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can check the extensions on Magento marketplace which can add the sorting options for you. Here is what I recommend https://marketplace.magento.com/mk-sortby.html

Comment: Extension no longer available.... there doesn't look to be an extension available for such feature currently

Answer (score 0):

**[Improved Sorting](https://marketplace.magento.com/invigoratesystems-module-improvedsorting.html)** extension provides the same functionality to sort by newest products.